# Can I use JavaScript to subscribe to WCF WSDualHttpBinding?

Tags: wcf, duplex

I have a web site that needs data to be pushed to it.  Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any other methods besides using HTML 5 WebSockets (I can't garauntee my clients will have HTML5 browers) and Comet (I'm not using java/tomcat).

I am not a big fan of using server-side ASP.NET for this particular project, and would prefer to use ASP.NET MVC or something like it.  Is it possible to tie JavaScript in with a duplex service?

Comment: Not to my knowledge considering the duplex binding is essentially opening an endpoint up on the client that the server can connect to. JavaScript wouldn't open an endpoint, but would just open a connection and hang on to it. (Though I may, in-fact, be way off base here)

Comment: Also Ws*HttpBinding is SOAP so you would have to mess around with all the SOAP envelope stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Well actually you can leverage the pollingduplex binding used for silverlight clients in javascript. There is an interesting blog post on this  by tomek over here: http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2009/07/pubsub-sample-using-http-polling-duplex.html